# What is roaming sensitivity?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, drivers, antenna

For my Signal King SK-999WN Wifi adapter, I installed the Ralink 3070 driver package `IS_Setup_ICS_081414_1.5.38.101.exe` available from MediaTek. The driver has an option *Roaming Sensitivity*, which by default is disabled:

[image: Screenshot of driver options]

*What is Roaming Sensitivity? When do I choose which value?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### What is Roaming Sensitivity? When do I choose which value?

This option is only useful if you are using wireless roaming where you have a wireless router and a wireless extender or similar product.

---

#### How roaming works

> Roaming is purely a client decision. The wireless client is
>   responsible for deciding it needs to roam, and then detecting,
>   evaluating, and roaming to an alternative AP. WLAN standards bodies
>   (such as IEEE) and industry bodies (such as Wi-Fi Alliance) do not
>   specify when a client should roam, or how the client roams.

Intel products use the name **Roaming Aggressiveness** and Ralink uses **Roaming Sensitivity**

> There are 5 settings to choose from. Here are the explanations of these five settings:
>
> - Lowest: Your wireless client will not roam. Only significant link quality degradation causes it to roam to another access point.
> - Medium-Low/Medium-High: Allow Roaming.
> - Medium: Balanced setting between not roaming and performance.
> - Highest: Your Wi-Fi client continuously tracks the link quality. If any degradation occurs, it tries to find and roam to a better access
>     point.
>
>   In Ralink, there are similar settings (and an additional "off" setting).

Source [What can I do if my wireless devices don't roam between my wireless router and TP-LINK's AP and Range Extender products?](http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?faqid=592)

Comment: I am using a Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter for Wi-Fi connectivity. I have a single ISP-controlled router where 2.4GHz and 5.0GHz band is using the same name. I have chosen the 5GHz band as the preferred in driver settings. With "roaming aggressiveness" set to medium, it always seems to choose 2.4GHz. With it "Disabled" it seems to select 5GHz. Might be due to a long distance to the router, but throughput is best in my case in 5GHz.