# Two router LAN without connecting cable

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan

Trying to create a single network which will cover two seperate buildings, so that only one set of login credentials are needed. However, buildings are in close proximity but entirely seperate, i.e. do not share mains or have data cable between. The only connection that new building has to old building is that they both share a telephone line, so the new building can get an internet connection.

Want to know if it's possible to create a LAN without daisy chaining the routers per-se, seeing as a connection to the line is already available in the new building and I want to avoid running new cabling/having two networks if I can help it.

Comment: How about using VPN?

Comment: yeah VPN as scott says. Or, set each "router" to "Wireless Bridge" that connects the "wireless routers" without a cable. The wireless routers may have to be the same model and they have to both support wireless bridge mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would like a Local Area Network (same subnet) without having to change wifi password all the time. IE. If a person walk form building A to build B for meetings, he or she would not need to change the SSID and wifi password setting.

Pls see if suggestions below works:

[Suggestion] "Router" on building A and "Wireless Access Point (AP)" on building B

1. You may set the Router A on building A as the PRIMARY router, with DHCP server while setting Router B on Building B in Access Point mode (without DHCP).
2. You may also set the AP with a different channel (ie. one is channel 6 while the other in channel 11) for easy monitoring of the signal strength.
3. In addition, you may adjust the "Roaming Sensitivity" (or Seamless connect) setting on the client Laptop/Tablet under WiFi card properties so that the WiFi card will automatically switch the AP/Router seamlessly when one signal strength (dB) goes weak.
   More info on setting roaming sensitivity => 
   [What is roaming sensitivity?](https://superuser.com/questions/819832/what-is-roaming-sensitivity])

Pls see picture and instruction below for more details:

[Link of instruction and picture source, by www.dd-wrt.com]
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge

[image: Picture source: www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge]