# Lag spikes since upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lag

EDIT: Sorry for not mentioning earlier: I've tried reducing the roaming sensitivity to no avail. I also fiddled with my router settings, which rendered it unusable for a short time before I reset the defaults.

I've been getting nasty lag spikes ever since I upgraded from Win7 to Win10 about 2 weeks ago. They are most noticeable during multiplayer gaming (since everything sort of locks up or stutters), but I'm sure that it's happening all the time.

The spikes happen one or two minutes apart, and last for about 3 seconds each.

I've tried looking for a solution, but nobody seems to even know where the problem is coming from, so I installed MS Network Monitor and set up a constant ping to www.google.com to try and catch the culprit. These were my findings:

Pinging Google once every second, printing the timestamp of each ping. Here you'll notice a sudden spike in response time (from 65ms to 500+). After the spike, it settles back down to 65ms.

[image]

Monitoring network traffic. Using the timestamp data from the ping command, I was able to isolate the network activity that was occurring during the spike. You'll notice that most of the traffic during those 3 seconds is related to wifi probe responses and wifi beacons.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I've done this test a few times, with no other network intensive programs running, and it's always this same group of network activities that happen during the lag spikes.

This didn't happen on Windows 7, so I think my router is not the problem. I have no idea what probes or beacons are. I see wifi hotspot names in the list, so I'm guessing that this is Windows trying to keep the list of hotspots up to date, but I don't understand why it has to lock up my connection when doing so.

If there is a way to delay this process, so that it doesn't happen every couple of minutes, that would be great. Ideally though, I'd like to fix it all together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is roaming sensitivity?](http://superuser.com/questions/819832/what-is-roaming-sensitivity)

Comment: Try disabling "roaming  sensitivity". See possible dupe.