# Lag spikes after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ping

I recently upgraded my OS to Windows 10 from Windows 7, but after doing so I started to have lag spikes in games.

There are 2 laptops and 3 phones connected to the Wi-Fi, so when I was using Windows 7, sometimes my ping were increasing to 100-150 ms from 50 ms for a couple of second when the other devices were using the bandwidth, but it was no big deal gameplay wise.

But now in Windows 10, my ping is always 50 ms no matter what. When my ping supposed to increase because of other connected devices, I just have a big lag spike where everything stops moving for 2-3 seconds then teleports to where they were supposed to be in 2-3 seconds. This is pretty bad gameplay wise compared to just increased ping for a couple of seconds.

I think this has to do something with Windows 10, about how it deals with increased ping. Any of you guys have the same kind of problem or know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I was using Window 7 for years and there is one game I play mainly, Dota 2. When I was playing it on Windows 7, my ping value that is shown in the game were increasing when some other devices on the network doing something like buffering a new video, then the game was issuing my commands with like 100ms delay. I just upgraded to Windows 10, now doing the same things on the other devices is not increasing my ping, instead it freezes the game entirely for a few seconds then goes back to normal.

Short version: In Windows 7, when my ping increases, my commands are delayed. In Windows 10, when my ping increases, the game just freezes for 2-3 seconds.

Comment: “But now in Windows 10, my ping is always 50 ms no matter what” - How is a lower ping time all the time worst then 100 ms increases for a couple seconds?  What you describe isn’t connected to Windows 10.

Comment: Relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/819832/what-is-roaming-sensitivity and https://superuser.com/questions/1011858/lag-spikes-since-upgrading-to-windows-10?rq=1

Comment: I didn’t ignore anything.  You said one thing then something else entirely.  You have not provided enough information to solve your problem though

Comment: Do you have any bluetooth devices nearby? They can interfere with WiFi to the point where pinging the router can time out.

Comment: Edit the question stop using comments to clarify your question.

Comment: First time using this website, sorry for not using it properly in my first post. There is no need to be a jerk though.