# Ethernet over Powerlines

Tags: ethernet, powerline-networking

I have a question about Ethernet over Powerlines.

I am trying to create a network between my main floor, and my basement. The thing is my basement is a separate apartment.

I am wondering if Ethernet over Powerline adapters could work in this situation?

Both the upstairs, and downstairs apartments have their own electrical meters. One main line comes into the house, and is split between the two meters. Both electrical meters are the older kind, with the little dials, not the newer digital ones if that makes any difference at all.

Comment: I tried a pair of these some while ago because of poor wireless reception upstairs when router was downstairs.

The result was massive packet loss between laptop and router (old house wiring, signal crossing fuse box). Of course large packet loss can cause problems with the internet connection.

In my experience they only work well in a house with very new electrical wiring. If the house wiring is old or the device are on different circuits (so the signal passes through a fuse box) then you get the packet loss.

When I tried using them on the same electrical circuit there was no issue.

Comment: To be 100% sure, the only option is to try it with two adapters. Newer adapters can handle different meters and so on, but to be REALLY sure, you have to just try.

Comment: Unless the wiring is faulty, you should generally be OK. But passing through an RCD/meter generally reduces the signal to worthlessness.

Comment: See also [TP -Link powerline adapters randomly disconnect](http://superuser.com/a/804708)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely that it will work. Or at least not work reliably.

It can be hard to predict whether two supplies are even on the same phase - if they are not, you won't have a connection at all. Even if they are, the RCD panels and meters will interfere.

Even running a wired Ethernet connection could be difficult if the two apartments have separate earthing.

I'd say that a wireless connection is going to be the safest and easiest option. If signal levels are challenging, you can easily use directional aerials to help boost the signal. This can be done cheaply with some simple hacks with tin foil, the Internet will show you how. If you are able to invest in the latest "AC" Wi-Fi standards, that will also help.