# WiFi powerline extender loses speed when I connect to WiFi

Tags: speed, powerline-networking, wifi-transfer

This is my home network:

- A modem router WiFI
- A TP-LINK PLC to go upstairs
- A laptop

[image: network]

**Laptop connected to BOSS**

When my laptop is connected directly via WiFi to the main modem-router (SSID BOSS), the speed is 76 Mbps.

**Laptop connected to TORCHWOOD**

When my laptop is connected via WiFi to PLC-WIFI (SSID TORCHWOOD), the speed between the TP Link PLCs is 17 Mbps

I do not understand the cause of this speed loss.

Comment: How long does it take to switch between both states? Right now my guess would be that only if you have something connected and some data is being transferred that whatever they use for detection is actually able to see errors that are happening and automatically downgrades.

Comment: My suspicion is that the PowerLine has something to do with the slow-down. Verify your setup against this [tp-link article](http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-409.html) and [makeuseof.com article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-tips-improve-speed-powerline-network/).

Comment: Seth It is instantaneous. I change my laptop connection between Boss and Torchwood and instantly changes the speed. I really do not understand why. Because the tool measures the speed of the power line (not my laptop).

Answer (score 4):

That sounds *about* right. Homeplug is usually slower than the rated speeds, and is affected by multiple things - line quality, the presence and  distance between your homeplug devices and 'noisy' devices. Our dryer used to cause my network connection to go down, for example. I have an answer here that goes into that in [somewhat more detail](https://superuser.com/a/950312/10165). Essentially any network segment is only as good as its weakest link.

Much like wifi, a good idea is to experiment and work out the best *locations* for such plugs and work out what the slowdowns are . Try the homeplug units at a nearer plug for example.

TPlink should have a tool for predicting speeds, which while apparently [inaccurate](http://www.linuxmediaserver.net/linux-basics/true-speed-of-powerline-adapters/), might give you a relative idea of signal quality.

While my current setup dosen't support it, [homeplug monitor](http://forum.ethernetovercoax.eu/index.php?topic=126.0) is a much better tool for powerusers, and lets you see SNR and such.

I'd finish by saying, your wifi speed and powerline networking speed are independant of each other and have different criteria affecting performance.

Comment: I'd agree with testing different locations for Torchwood, starting with right next to Boss. If it gets good throughput there, then it is likely the wiring in the house that is to blame. If it is slow there, it could potentially be faulty equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the layout of your house, but it is likely that there is either a physical barrier (solid wall or floor you may not know about?) in between to of the wirelessly connected components, or there may be some sort of electromagnetic interference from another device (plasma TVs cause a lot of problems). I would check for anything that may be causing interference and move your relay (SSID TORCHWOOD) away from them. If that does not solve your problem, the delay is likely between your router and your signal relay (SSID TORCHWOOD)

Comment: But the problem in en ths power line speed. It is a PLC.